# How do I send the right data via post request, to satisfy this firebase rulset?

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am really struggeling all day with this and therefore would honestly appreciate any help...

Currently I have an app with working auth system.
An user is able to add data to the firebase. The user adds to values in each post.
The values are "description" and "name".
What I want to achieve is, that an user can only see data, he himself posted on my firebase.

Therefore the code in firebase, I use, looks as following:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "notes": {
      "$uid": {
        ".read": "auth != null && auth.uid == $uid",
        ".write": "auth != null"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But the stored values have the following structure:
Backend-name
notes
0
description: "the value of this"
name: "the value of that"

If I try to get the data out of this database, I only get an 401 error (access denied). So I think the mistake is, that the uid is missing in this.

How would I achieve this?
I would like to share some parts of the code now. If this is not enough, I would share all of it with you. But nevertheless I hope this is sufficient.

Here come the relevant parts:

note.service.ts

```
private notes: Note[] = [];

  setNotes(notes: Note[]) {
    this.notes = notes;
    this.notesChanged.next(this.notes.slice());
  }

getNotes() {
    return this.notes.slice();
  }
```

note.model.ts

```
export class Note {
  public name: string;
  public description: string;


  constructor(name: string, desc: string) {
    this.name = name;
    this.description = desc;
  }
}
```

data.storage.ts

```
  loadNotes() {
    return this.http
      .get<Note[]>(
        'https://XXXXXXX.firebaseio.com/notes.json'
      )
      .pipe(
        map(notes => {
          return notes.map(note => {
            return {
              ...note
            };
          });
        }),
        tap(notes => {
          this.noteService.setNotes(notes);
        })
      );
  }
```

The content of a form containing name and description are than send as one value to firebase. The structure can be seen above.

So how would you make this happen?

Thank you very much for reading this and helping me!

**EDIT:** I am not sure, if anyone reads this... but I am going to try anyways.
I am already recieving an idToken, changed the get request to ad the idToken, but don't know how to change the put request accordingly.

And I am not even sure, if the firebase rules are okay.

Comment: have you though about using angularfire?

Comment: The process for authenticating REST requests is documented here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/auth I'd consider using a Firebase SDK for your platform though, as that handles many of the edge-cases involved.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Thanks for your advise. I think I am almost there actually... so I would like to stick to this, since I have put effort into this. But I can't finish it. It' incredibly frustrating.

Comment: @JSmith I'd have to look into that. but maybe next time. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The request is denied as your rules state that only Auth'ed user can access the document.

You already say you have a working Auth system so the step required for the REST request to work is the `auth` token that Frank mention in the document above.

That token is obtainable by this method `getIdToken`:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User#getidtoken

Then you can insert in your request like:

```
https://XXXXXXX.firebaseio.com/notes.json?auth=<ID_TOKEN>
```

Comment: so okay, I edited the get request accordingly. But what should I do about the put request? Do I need to edit it the same way?

Comment: Yes. In fact all request will need to add the ID_TOKEN. It will change overtime and generated by the library in link above.